# Powershell: Export-Excel is not exporting data rows, only the headers

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export some data into an excel worksheet and it's only exporting the headers, not the rows of data.  I've verified the rows of data are in the variable $info.  Why are the rows of data not being exported?  Thanks for the help.

The $info variable is filled up by this code:

```
$info = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $serverList -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object csname, lastbootuptime, LocalDateTime | Sort-Object lastbootuptime | Format-Table
```

**Export-Excel Code:**

```
$info | Select-Object csname,LastBootupTime,LocalDateTime | Export-Excel -Path $destinationPath -WorksheetName LastBootUpTime
```

**Current Result:**

[image]

**Desired Result:**

[image]

Comment: If you don't `Select-Object` and instead pipe directly to the export, does it contain the rows?

Comment: What's in your variable `$info`? How do you fill it up? What happens when you do an `Export-CSV` instead of `Export-Excel`?

Comment: @AndrewDavis, when I don't do Select-Object, it only exports what looks to be GUID's,

Comment: @Olaf, What you see in the Desired Result is what is in the variable $info.  I fill it up by using this code:  $info = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $serverList -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object csname, lastbootuptime, LocalDateTime | Sort-Object lastbootuptime | Format-Table

Comment: @Olaf, it does the same thing when I try to export-csv.  I intend to work on multiple worksheets and that's why I'm using Export-Excel.

Comment: Please remove the `| Format-Table` from your command line you create your variable `$info` with.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, that fixed it.  If you want to put that as the answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use format cmdlets like `Format-Table` you turn rich and powerful dot-net objects into stupid and boring pixels on the screen. ;-) So the solution in this case is to omit the `Format-Table` at the end of your variable declaration.

```
$info = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $serverList -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | 
    Select-Object -Property csname, lastbootuptime, LocalDateTime | 
        Sort-Object -Property LastBootupTime

$info | Export-Excel -Path $destinationPath -WorksheetName LastBootUpTime
```